# Ubuntu 14.04 Netbeans 7.4 installation problem

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, netbeans

I have a problem when I want install netbeans7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have openJDK :

```
morgan@morgan-laptop:~/Téléchargements$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.6) (7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

When i try to install it (sorry for error message, it's a french version) :

```
morgan@morgan-laptop:~/Téléchargements$ sudo sh ./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh 
Configuration du programme d'installation...
Recherche d'une JVM sur le système...
Extraction des données d'installation...
Exécution de l''assistant d''installation...
Impossible d'initialiser l'Interface Utilisateur
Running in headless mode

Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

And this is my kernel version :

```
morgan@morgan-laptop:~/Téléchargements$ uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

I don't anderstand why it's not work. I have seen de same problem (other topic) but for resolve it they uninstall openJDK for Sun JDK. Yet it worked on ubuntu 12.04 with openJDK

Comment: please add answers in a "answer", not in the question, you can also answer your own question, as we do not use "solved" here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not install jdk, for solve them :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Answer (score -2):

The cleanest install Netbeans in Ubuntu is written in the command line: `sudo apt-get install netbeans`. It'll install the 7.0.1 version, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This is an English only site, please include an English translation